Server Error Can't connect to the server: Unexpected HTTP response code from the identity service: 404. only on iOS
I would like to share an issue regarding the login process using the Salesforce SDK on iOS (latest version of the operating system). Currently, without using a VPN, I am unable to proceed with the app login and receive the following error message: "Server Error: Can't connect to the server. Unexpected HTTP response code from the identity service: 404."
Below is the response from Salesforce when debugging using Xcode (without using VPN):
CLASS: SFIdentityCoordinator 
SF Data from CRM: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x303daf3a0> { URL: https://test.salesforce.com/id/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx } 
{ Status Code: 404, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private"
    );
    "Content-Security-Policy" =     (
        "upgrade-insecure-requests"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Thu, 25 Apr 2024 13:15:42 GMT"
    );
    "Set-Cookie" =     (
        "CookieConsentPolicy=0:0; path=/; expires=Fri, 25-Apr-2025 13:15:42 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; secure",
        "LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:0; path=/; expires=Fri, 25-Apr-2025 13:15:42 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; secure",
        "BrowserId=xxxxxxx; domain=.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 25-Apr-2025 13:15:42 GMT; Max-Age=31536000"
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    );
    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (
        Identity
    );
    "X-Content-Type-Options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
}

We are using SalesforceSDK version 8.4.x and the latest version of Xcode. Interestingly, when using a VPN and connecting to America, the login is successful.
Do you have any suggestions or solutions that you could share with us?
Thank you

Hi, just an update: the issue has been reported on Salesforce as a known issue, specifically affecting iOS users. You can find more details here: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000z01vmAAA/unexpected-http-response-code-from-the-identity-service-404-after-ios-app-login-for-government-orgs-on-ios-version-1731.
